# How can i migrate Redmine database 1.3.0 to 2.5.0

Tags: redmine, migrate

I'm currently using Redmine 1.3.0 and newly installed Redmine 2.5.0.
How can I migrate old redmine database to the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply follow the [database update instructions on the redmine wiki](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Step-6-Database-schema-objects-creation).:

- install new version of redmine
- configure new version
- run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

This will automatically upgrade your database to the latest version.

Be sure to check the admin section for new settings and adjust them.